# Best way to make radiobuttons from other content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a page with contact-cards, ordered with a flex-box. If you click on a card, some information about that person should appear.

My solutions so far (also shown below):

- Use radiobuttons with absolute position & size set in px.

  - This has the downside that the dynamic sizes of flexboxes are no longer usable. And the sizes are hardcoded this way.
- Use radiobuttons with default position & size.

  - This has the downside that the button floats above the card instead of in front of it.

My question:
How do I make a radiobutton float in front of an flexbox element and use it's size?

```js
// This function is just to show radiobuttons working
function updatePersonnelParagraph() {
  document.getElementById("personnel-paragraph").innerHTML = "";
  const ele = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
    if (ele[i].type === "radio" && ele[i].name === "Personnel" && ele[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("personnel-paragraph").innerHTML +=
        ele[i].value;
      break;
    }
}

window.onload = updatePersonnelParagraph;
```

```css
.personnel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.personnel-radiobutton1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  // opacity: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.personnel-radiobutton2 {
  z-index: 1;
  // opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+h3 {
  color: blue;
}

.personnel-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}

.personnel-paragraph {
  margin: 10px 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="personnel-container">
  <div class="personnel-item">
    <input type="radio" class="personnel-radiobutton1" id="Person1" name="Personnel" value="Person1" checked onclick="updatePersonnelParagraph()" />
    <h3 style="margin: 0">Person1</h3>
    <img src="./assets/Person1.jpg" alt="Pic of Person1" class="personnel-item-picture" />
    <p>This is Person1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="personnel-item">
    <input type="radio" class="personnel-radiobutton2" id="Person2" name="Personnel" value="Person2" checked onclick="updatePersonnelParagraph()" />
    <h3 style="margin: 0">Person2</h3>
    <img src="./assets/Person2.jpg" alt="Pic of Person2" class="personnel-item-picture" />
    <p>This is Person2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="personnel-paragraph" class="personnel-paragraph"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t really get what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: Are you trying to make the radio buttons as big as your whole card and be in front of it, for the user to be able to click and “activate” the whole thing that way? You are already using JS here, so I think trying to do this with radio buttons and `:checked` at any cost, makes rather little sense to begin with. Set up a click handler for `.personnel-item`, and then deal with whatever needs doing in JS.

Comment: Fair, I was trying to use as little JS as possible, but it would make a lot of sense here. Thanks!